# How do I share common methods between view controllers in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, methods

In my app there are numerous view controllers which have their own purposes. However, underneath they do share some need for common maintenance work that could use the same method code instead of each having its own copy of the code, literally pasted in.

Is there a way to share the code of these common methods ?  I see two possibilities:

1) either one copy of code truly shared in memory as in a special maintenance object of methods

or

2) written once in a block of code but allocated many times as needed by each view.

Which of these is the correct path or what is the correct path, and HOW would it be implemented in the most simple manner ?

Kindness pls, new coder in the room.

Thanks.

-Ric

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Note: This is an old question/answer reflective of Apple practices at the time, and answered for a new coder looking for a simple solution they can understand (as requested in the question). There are better and more testable ways to achieve this, using [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

The best way to achieve what you want is to create a common parent class for your view controllers. So instead of inheriting directly from `UIViewController`, each of your custom classes will inherit from `SomeFeatureViewController` (where `SomeFeature` describes the common feature provided), this class inherits from `UIViewController`. Now, each of your actual view controllers will inherit from `SomeFeatureViewController` and any common methods (also any common instance variables used by these methods) can be placed in this parent class.

```
@interface SomeFeatureViewController : UIViewController
{
    int common_iVars;
}
- (void)commonMethods;
@end

@interface ActualViewController : SomeFeatureViewController
{
    int specific_iVars;
}
- (void)specificMethods;
@end
```

Comment: Do you have any example of it ?? I have issue relates in storyboard. One Designed UIViewController not inheritances to another one.

Comment: 6 Years down the lane - Does this solution work if my view controllers subclass from different view controllers.

Comment: @Dibzmania no. This is an old and outdated approach anyway, reflective of how UIKit encouraged the bad practice of massive view controllers. Now in Swift you can use extensions, or protocols with default implementations, or event better, composition, composing your VC out of other classes (or value types) that actually do the work. For example a ViewModel or Presentation layer, re-used by multiple controllers.

Comment: @jhabbott Well after posting my previous comment, I did some digging and solved my issue by writing up a category on UIViewController and putting the shared code in it. All VC's anyways extend UIViewController, so my problem was resolved (found this approach on one another SO answer). Anyways We are shortly (finally !!) migrating our application to Swift and I will remember to use the suggestions you provided

Comment: Yes - the category on `UIViewController` is mentioned in another answer on this question as well. It works, but it is equivalent to adding a global function - all view controllers get it. Have a think about using composition... this means implement the functionality in a separate object and ViewControllerA creates and uses one of these objects, so does ViewControllerB - that's how the functionality is shared. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: Composition over inheritance and not viceversa!

Comment: @denis_lor I totally agree. The OP indicated that they were a new developer and that they wanted simple (easiest for them to understand and implement). Also the iOS frameworks made it very difficult to practice good composition, forcing you to inherit from different `UIViewController` subclasses. So without delivering an entire computer science class in an SO answer, plus the workarounds needed to shoe-horn a clean composition-based solution into UIKit, I think this answer was probably the best answer for the OP at the time. However, I'll edit in a note to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you should do a class with all the common methods and then subclass it. Say you have MyCommonViewController : UIViewController and then for each different view controller do MySpecificVIewController : MyCommonViewController

Answer (score 0):

As well stated by jhabbott, a subclass of UIViewController is one good solution.

If that's not an option (e.g. you can't change the class hierarchy), another option is to create a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20) on UIViewController to add the methods and properties you need. This will make your methods available on every UIViewController, including all the standard subclasses, without any extra work on your part. With this solution you cannot directly add ivars, although you can fake it up well enough using [associative references](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAssociativeReferences.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, what I ended up doing was to create a Singleton object and put all my common methods there.  This meant that all my View Controllers could utilize the common methods of the Singleton. Maybe this is a bit too open if the project was being developed by a team of programmers but as it is just me I know that all the controllers have similar requirements in processing.  So the Singleton approach seemed to work.

It also fit the project because at the time of the question all the View Controllers had been created and to make them a subclass of a parent class seemed to be a retrofit, though I agree that if part of an initial design, it may be a better approach.  I do thank the 3 who gave the time to answer.

Comment: I disagree with this silution. First of all because when I see a singleton I always see it as a global variable, so I immediately try to ask myself if is really required. And the second reason is that in this way you are really broken the hierarchy and objects that share functionality are not related each other.

Comment: Well, 4 years later and a lot more experience, I completely agree with you.